# Probability of 5 card texas holdem poker royal flush

Tags: combinatorics, games

How would I calculate the probability of getting a royal flush with 2 player Texas holdem poker.

A single randomly shuffled 52 card deck, 2 players (p1 & p2) are sequentially dealt 4 cards i.e. p1 gets card 1, card 3 and p2 gets card 2, card 4. Then 3 cards are placed on the table (Flop), followed by a discarded card, then the 4th card (Turn) on the table followed by a discarded card and then the 5th card (River). Therefore there are 5 'community' cards, in addition to the 2 cards each player has. With this the player can make their 5 card royal flush.

P(royal flush ) = 4**C**1 / 52**C**5 = 1/649740

https://ctools.ece.utah.edu/Probability/Combinatorics/ProbCombEx15.htm

However the above does not take into account

- Playing with 2 players, where the first 4 cards dealt are
  divided between the 2 players?
- p1 and p2 can use the 5 community cards along with their hand to create the royal flush?

What is the probability of p1 getting a royal flush?